# DataTexture with LuminanceFormat UnsignedShort is not renderable

Tags: three.js

I've a small question concerning GL_LUMINANCE with uint16 data. I have some OpenGL code I want to bring to WebGL / three.js:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, myColor, (ushort)width, 
             (ushort)height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, imageData);
```

When running this basic sample code I get the error

```
texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. 
It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
```

I'm not an expert so maybe this does not work at all?
So thats the basic sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
      <canvas id="c" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid">No canvas functionality</canvas>
      <script>
          var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
          var scene = new THREE.Scene();
          var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 1000);
          var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas } );

          var test = new Uint16Array(2048 * 2048);
          for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
              test[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 0xFFFF) + 1);
          }

          var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
          var tex = new THREE.DataTexture(test, 2048, 2048, THREE.LuminanceFormat, THREE.UnsignedShortType);
          var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: tex } );
          var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, this.material);
          material.map.needsUpdate = true;
          scene.add(mesh);

          var bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( mesh, 0xFF0000 );
          bbox.update();
          scene.add( bbox );

          camera.position.z = 1;

          function render() {
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

          requestAnimationFrame(render);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an answer, but your example works with `THREE.LuminanceFormat`, `Uint8Array` and `THREE.UnsignedByteType`. Check the WebGL spec for limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging on the net i found this forum entry:

[There is no such thing as gl.SHORT or gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT for textures in OpenGL ES 2.0 nor WebGL](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/webgl-dev-list/oa_hC83oe-U/fkYbScsvA3cJ)

> There is no such thing as gl.SHORT or gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT for textures
>   in OpenGL ES 2.0 nor WebGL
>
> From the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec these are the only formats support
>
> ```
> RGBA UNSIGNED_BYTE  
> RGB UNSIGNED_BYTE  
> RGBA UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4
> RGBA UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1  
> RGB UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5  
> LUMINANCE_ALPHA UNSIGNED_BYTE  
> LUMINANCE UNSIGNED_BYTE  
> ALPHA UNSIGNED_BYTE
> ```
>
> OES_texture_float adds
>
> ```
> RGBA FLOAT 
> RGB FLOAT 
> LUMINANCE_ALPHA FLOAT 
> LUMINANCE FLOAT 
> ALPHA FLOAT
> ```

So this solves it for me :)

Comment: So how did you render your uint16 data? :)